# NSStatusWindowLevel disabled when presenting window sheet

Tags: macos, cocoa, objective-c-2.0

I'm using an `NSWindow` and set it's level to `NSStatusWindowLevel` :

```
[aWindow setLevel:NSStatusWindowLevel];
```

Now, when I present a sheet (`self` is my sheet window)

```
modalAnswer = 0;
[NSApp beginSheet:self modalForWindow:aWindow modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:NULL contextInfo:nil];
[self makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

then the window doesn't show up above the dock, it hides underneath (meaning that `NSStatusWindowLevel` doesn't work anymore).
I've tried changing the level of the sheet window, but it won't work.

What's causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked for technical support and they found it was a silly mistake : sheets normally are modal, but I was making it modal myself too.

> The combination of beginModalSessionForWindow and runModalSession is the issue here.
>   It appears to be servicing the default run loop which is causing the menu bar and Dock to appear over your window.
>
> I'm a bit confused as to why you are calling beginSheet:modalForWindow, and then using NSApp's beginModalSessionForWindow.  Why do you manually add a modal session? Sheets are automatically modal to whatever window it is attached to.  I am used to seeing the use of "beginModalSessionForWindow" without sheets on top of them.